# Check Discrepancy of Running Balance

Tags: running-balance

i want to check discrepancy in running balance in SQL ,want to find a row from after where my running balance not correct could anyone please guide me in this problem will be thankfull to you

i searched it out but could not find

Comment: Please give us the environment you are using (mysql, sql server, oracle, ...). You could also add exemples of dataset (tables name, columns name, some data) and the expected output. You can also share what you have tried so far.